Why is my class variable state not updating?
I have a bug here in which my variable "current_room" Is not updating in the "GameState" class.
I'm new to posting on stack so I'm not sure how to make this actually look like code when I'm typing out this post.
class GameState:
    def __init__(self, current_room=None, player_inventory=None):
        self.current_room = current_room if current_room else "Chapel"  # Start in the Chapel by default
        self.player_inventory = player_inventory if player_inventory else []

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "current_room": self.current_room,
            "player_inventory": self.player_inventory
        }

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, state_dict):
        return cls(state_dict["current_room"], state_dict["player_inventory"])

def move(game_state, game_map):
    current_room_state = game_state.current_room
    current_room_info = game_map[current_room_state]

    # Get player's input for movement command
    move_command_input = input("Which direction would you like to move?: ").strip().lower()

    # Check if the move command is valid
    if move_command_input in directions:
        direction = directions[move_command_input]
        if direction in current_room_info["Exits"]:
            new_room = current_room_info["Exits"][direction]
            print(f"You moved to the {new_room}.")
            game_state.current_room = new_room  # Update the current room
        else:
            print("You can't move in that direction.")
    else:
        print("Invalid move command.")

    return game_state

game_map = {
    "Chapel": {
        "Description": " I am standing in a majestic chapel."
                       "\n             There is a coffin in front of me.",
        "Exits": {"north": "Window room", "east": "Tunnel", "west": "Ballroom (Fireplace)", "south": "Stairs"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": ["coffin"]
    },
    "Window": {
        "Description": "There is a big window at the top of the stairs."
                       "\nThe view from here is amazing...",
        "Exits": {"s": "Chapel"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": ["window"]
    },
    "Ballroom (Fireplace)": {
        "Description": "\n I am standing in the grand ballroom..."
                       "\n Sure will you had a girl to dance with don't you?",
        "Exits": {"e": "Chapel"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": []
    },
    "Tunnel": {
        "Description": "\nI am in a tunnel with limestone walls."
                       "\nThere is a large stone door with a Sapphire in the middle.",
        "Exits": {"w": "Chapel"},
        "Items": ["bloody knife"],
        "Objects": []
    },
    "Stairs": {
        "Description": "\nI am in a dingy looking stairwell."
                       "\nBroken glass is everywhere, looks like an explosion happened?",
        "Exits": {"n": "Chapel", "e": "Kettle Room", "s": "Room", "w": "Dungeon"},
        "Items": ["broken glass"],
        "Objects": []
    },
    "Room": {
        "Description": "\nYou are in a plain, nondescript room.",
        "Exits": {"n": "Armory"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": []
    },
    "Kettle Room": {
        "Description": "\nThis looks like their version of a kitchen."
                       "\nLost of pots, pans, and kettles are in the sink...",
        "Exits": {"n": "Head Room", "w": "Stairs"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": []
    },
    "Head Room": {
        "Description": "\nIm standing in the room filled with animal heads."
                       "\nIt looks like these guys loved to hunt...",
        "Exits": {"e": "Pantry", "s": "Kettle Room"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": []
    },
    "Pantry": {
        "Description": "\nFound the pantry, Might as well take a bite!"
                       "\nI wonder why they need a pantry in a chapel?",
        "Exits": {"w": "Head Room", "e": "Lab"},
        "Items": ["Food"],
        "Objects": ["Basket"]
    },
    "Lab": {
        "Description": "\nA Lab? What kind of a chapel is this?"
                       "\nAnyways, I wonder what they might be doing in here?",
        "Exits": {"w": "Pantry"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": ["chemicals"]
    },
    "Dungeon": {
        "Description": "\nThe dungeon seems to be a bit dusty,"
                       "\nThere are skeletons on the ground...",
        "Exits": {"e": "Stairs", "s": "Torture Chamber"},
        "Items": ["metal chain"],
        "Objects": ["gate"]
    },
    "Torture Chamber": {
        "Description": "\nOne of the worst rooms in the whole castle",
        "Exits": {"n": "Dungeon", "e": "Armory"},
        "Items": ["bones", "Sword"],
        "Objects": ["Skeleton", "Bones"]
    },
    "Armory": {
        "Description": "\nLooks like you found the weapons hub of this whole place,"
                       "\nReally Staring to look more like a castle rather than a chapel",
        "Exits": {"w": "Torture Chamber"},
        "Items": [],
        "Objects": []
    }
}

View of the game map:
                  Window
                    |
Ballroom -------- Chapel ----- Tunnel
(Fireplace)         |
                    |              Head Room -- Pot Room -- Lab
                    |                 |
Dungeon --------- Stairs --------- Kettle Room
   |                |
Torture---Armory    |
                    |
                  Room

moves = ["n", "e", "s", "w", "take", "slide", "move", "turn", "climb", "push", "circle"]
items = []
# Items you can pick up

edible_items = []
objects = []

I've tried a few different methods of updating my current_room variable, but the main problem is that the value of current_room is not being passed to the game state. Some of my failed attempts include a variable called "new_room". In which the direction of the exit would be stored in the variable, and the new_room variable would be stored in the game_state.current_room. But that would work because for some reason, the value would not be transferred. I've worked with python for about a year, and this is a problem that i haven't encountered in the past.

I suggest you develop a Minimal Reproducible Example that demonstrates your problem

Terminology note: those are not class variables, they are instance variables
